# How to alignment the content what stored as unicode

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode

I have stored some degree symbol as Unicode.
When I print that, they can't align with the title.

--

```
creat table if not exists model_list(
model_No VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
classification VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Element VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Sensor_size VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`FOV(H)` NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, `FOV(V)` NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, `FOV(D)` NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Fno FLOAT NOT NULL,
`TTL(mm)` FLOAT NOT NULL,
Image_Circle FLOAT NOT NULL,
CRA NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
RI VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
TV_Distortion VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`EFL(mm)` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`BFL(mm)` FLOAT NOT NULL,
`Sensor(one_case)` VARCHAR(20),
`BPF(nm)` VARCHAR(50) );

 INSERT INTO model_list
 (model_No, classification, Element, Sensor_size, `FOV(H)`, `FOV(V)`, `FOV(D)`, Fno, `TTL(mm)`, Image_Circle, 
        CRA, RI, TV_Distortion, `EFL(mm)`, `BFL(mm)`, `Sensor(one_case)`, `BPF(nm)`) VALUES
 ("J6450", "Rear view", "4G1GM", '1/2.7"', N'135°', N'70°', N'165°',2.0,16.0,6.80, N'15.2°',"45.o%","-28.3%",2.7,4.1,"AR0230",NULL);
```

just like the image, they can't be aligned.

https://imgur.com/a/UvVJGR3

Comment: Which OS?  What "cmd" or "terminal" tool?  What character set is used for that tool.  Here's a much shorter test case; I works fine in Ubuntu with a "terminal":  `SELECT '1/2.7"' AS a, N'135°' AS b, N'70°' AS c;`

Comment: To help debug your situation, please provide `SELECT HEX(\`FOV(V)\`);`